# Etimología de verbos como "arremangar" y "arrebañar"

Tags: gramática, etimología, verbos, prefijos

En el diccionario de la RAE tenemos:

> **[mangar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OC1auaX)**
>
> De *manga*.
>
> 2. tr. p. us. Vestir una prenda de mangas. U. t. c. prnl.

Usando el prefijo *[re-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFxyLmQ)* en el sentido de "hacia atrás", tenemos:

> **[remangar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vs0YRuj)**
>
> 1. tr. Levantar, recoger hacia arriba las mangas o la ropa. U. t. c. prnl.

Sin embargo, también existe:

> **[arremangar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3iYJmMr)**
>
> 1. tr. remangar. U. t. c. prnl.

Esta inclusión de "arr-" al principio de la palabra no es exclusiva de este verbo, ya que existen también *[arrebañar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3gvMxDk)* (de "rebañar"), *[arrebozar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3hKzUeU)* (de "rebozar") y otras. No estoy seguro de si lo que se pone delante del verbo es un simple prefijo *a-* que hace que se duplique la *r*, o si es más bien un prefijo *arre-* delante del verbo original. ¿Podría tener algo que ver con el *-arr-* de *nubarrón* o de *bicharraco*? ¿O es simplemente una variante coloquial del prefijo *re-*? ¿Qué hace que se formen estas palabras?

Comment: Se me ocurre que hay algún proceso de alternancia irregular ahí. ¿Tendrá algo que ver *ar-* con el latín *ad-*? En *[arrepentir](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrepentirse#Espa.C3.B1ol)* parece ser el caso, *arremeter* pinta igual. Quizá el mero hecho de que existan palabras con *arre-* basta para que se produzca el "contagio".

Comment: Yo creo que estas formaciones no son más que reflejos del uso del prefijo *a-* (http://dle.rae.es/?id=003XJY1) en verbos como *acuartelar*, *apestar*, *asegurar*, *atornillar*... No se da solo en verbos que empiezan por *re-*; se me ocurre algún otro coloquialismo como *afusilar*.

Comment: Yo el único similar que conocía era ["arrancar"](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discusión:arrascar) en lugar de "rascar". Podrían ser vulgarismos que se han vuelto tan populares que el DRAE termina por aceptarlos e incluirlos?

Comment: Arremangar viene del prefijo a y remangar. Donde a significa "sin", re significa "denuevo" y mangar significa "parte de una prenda que cubre el brazo". Por tanto, los que preguntas se refiere al regionalismo del lenguaje. En algunas zonas (como México) se utiliza arremangar y otras remangar. Cómo en esta palabra, añadir "a" antes se debe a usos de lenguaje por región, no tanto a la definición per se.

Comment: yo creo que es mas bien el prefijo "a" I no "arr" para hace algo como 
abrazar, anochecer, abrigar, aluzar , alistar, arrebatar, etc.

Answer (score 3):

El prefijo no es *arr-*, sino [*a-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-#Spanish) (de Latín, *ad-*). Cuando una palabra que empieza con *r-* se convierte en la segunda parte de una palabra compuesta (cuya primera parte termina con una vocal), ortográficamente se cambia a *-rr-* para mantener el sonido de *erre* (en lugar de *ere*).

Puedes ver este cambio en estas palabras:

- *velocirraptor, virrey, barbirrojo, bajorrelieve, grecorromano, antirreligioso*

Y, como notas, en los verbos compuestos de [*a-* + *r...*](https://es.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categor%C3%ADa:ES:Palabras_con_el_prefijo_a-&pagefrom=afervorizar#mw-pages):

- *arrebozar, arreglar, arremeter, arrepentirse, arrugar, arruinar*
- *arramblar (rambla), arriesgar (riesgo), arrinconar (rincón), arrodillar (rodilla)*

Y de otros prefijos:

- *derramar (ramo), irradiar, irregular, surrealismo* etc

---

**Fuente:**

<sup>• [*Prefixes in Latin and Romance and the satellite-/verb-framed distinction**](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000295/current.pdf), Víctor Acedo Matellán</sup>