# Allophone preserving orthography in compound words

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación

A few compound words in Spanish, where the original word has "n", are written with "m" to represent [m], the allophone <sup>[1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Sonidos_conson%C3%A1nticos) [2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI#cite_note-N-20)</sup> of /n/ which occurs before a bilabial consonant (/p/, /b/) <sup>3 4</sup>:

- tampoco  ([*ta**n p**oco*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=tampoco))
- también  ([*ta**n b**ien*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=tambi%C3%A9n))
- balompié ([*baló**n p**ie*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balompi%C3%A9#Spanish))
- ciempiés  ([*cie**n p**ies*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciempi%C3%A9s))
- tentempié ([*tente e**n p**ié*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZUM7MgT))
- biempensante ([*bie**n p**ensante*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=TD5Yy16ToD6j4lHhMY))

Likewise [word-initial "r-" becomes "-rr-"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20152/18348) in compound words to preserve the trill.

Does this kind of allophone preserving orthography occur with any other phonemes in compound words?

---

<sup>3. Also before nasal /m/, though this isn't expressed orthographically, either because this would create a double letter, which the RAE frowns upon e.g. *co**nm**igo, i**nm**ortal*, or due to a rule similar to the exception before *v*:</sup>

> <sup>**m.** ...</sup>
>   <sup>2. Debe escribirse *m* delante de *b* y *p* (*ambiguo*, *campo*), **mientras que se escribe *n* ante la letra *v* (*envío*, *invasión*).** No obstante, hay algún caso en que, por respetarse las grafías etimológicas, puede aparecer *n* ante *b*: *Canberra*, *Gutenberg* (→ n, 2).</sup>
>
> <sup>[*m - DPD*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=JGgOANLgtD6ancygWL#2)</sup>

> <sup>**n.** ...</sup>
>   <sup>2. Delante de *b* nunca se escribe *n*, salvo en el caso de algunos nombres propios extranjeros en los que se respeta la grafía originaria, como *Gutenberg*, *Hartzenbusch* o *Canberra*. No deben escribirse con *n* ante *p* los compuestos con bien (→ biempensante).</sup>
>
> <sup>[*n - DPD*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=3sqAFPmgTD6e025tQP#2)</sup>

Comment: Interesting Meta post to read: [How do we show how things are pronounced?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/1674). Not that I am correcting your post, just mentioning for future usages.

Comment: *in-* loses the *-n-* in front of *r-*, *n-*, but that's not quite exactly the same process.  It's the only thing close that I can think of off the top of my head, though

Comment: @guifa I think that particular change was happening already back in Latin.

Comment: so, balompie and Ciempies is correct ? can we create other compound words like "empaz" instead of en paz ? i actually have heard a lot of people pronouncing "empaz" instead of "en paz" and i think is due the same usage and ease of using "M" instead of "N" before the pronunciation of "P"

Comment: @Mike Yep [*balompié*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4uYBXPz) and [*ciempiés*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9AvIv81) are both RAE approved. And yep, the exact same thing happened historically with the prefix *en-* e.g. [*empacar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ek5WQHQ) (*en-* + *pacar*) etc, and could happen in future compound words.

Comment: @pablodf76 Indeed, although it still affects neologisms.  That's partly why I said it wasn't exactly the same ;-)

Comment: @Mike Yes, actually pronouncing "empaz" is perfectly correct. "En paz" sounds and acts like a single word, so the "n" gets changed into "m" as it normally does.

Comment: The case of "nm" staying like that is probably related to many speakers actually pronouncing it like that. I do.

Comment: Also not sure if they really count, but vino+agrio gives vinagre... but it's not really a compound word, not any more. There are also cases where the syllable boundary moves: por + Dios + -ero = por-dio-se-ro, camión + -ero = ca-mio-ne-ro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría argumentarse que la H o la G que separan la U intervocálica de la vocal que la precede al formar algunas palabras derivadas, no tiene más sentido que el de reflejar ortográficamente el cambio de pronunciación de `[u]` por `[w]` en dichas palabras.

Por ejemplo, de [*correa*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Awwz8hW) + el sufijo diminutivo [*-uela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0xveOx) tenemos [*corre**h**uela* o *corre**g**üela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AxxFP9h) en vez de **correuela*.
Lo mismo sucede con [*lamprea*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MrKz0DJ) → [*lampre**h**uela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MrTXdDM), y más o menos también con [*sarao*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XHqAgfo) + [*-ete*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H3Sohu5) → [*sara**gü**ete*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XHlAIfs) en vez de **saraoete*.

No puedo dar ejemplos de palabras compuestas que reflejen lo anterior, por la sencilla razón de que en español no existen hoy palabras que empiecen por U + vocal: todas están precedidas de H o G (con la excepción de la arcaica [*uebos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0wfjjb)). ¿Quizá por el mismo motivo? No puedo ahora revisar la etimología de todas ellas, pero estoy seguro de que en muchos casos esa misma H o G cumplen el mismo papel de reflejar el cambio de pronunciación de la U cuando precede a una vocal.

Comprendo que quizá esto no responde exactamente a tu pregunta, pero me pareció relevante.